# Stopping Windows service does not kill processes (service uses ant)

Tags: windows, java, service

I have a Windows service on Windows Server 2008 R2 that I set-up using `instsrv` on the `srvany.exe` executable. The three values in the `Parameters` key are set as follows:

```
AppDirectory  C:\selenium-grid
Application   C:\ant\bin\ant.bat
AppParameters launch-hub
```

The service starts fine and two Java processes appear in the Task Manager when it starts (one process is ant and the other is a Java class launched by ant). When I stop the service the status of the service changes to stopped but the two Java processes do not go away.

How do I get the processes to stop when I stop the service?

Comment: whats in ant.bat if there is more then one exe in there that may be the issue.

Comment: Is this an installation of the srvany.exe service?

Comment: Yes, the service install uses `srvany.exe`. I have added that clarification to the question.

Comment: One process is ant itself while the other is a Java class launched by ant. (Updated the question to clarify this.)

Answer (score 7):

Unvortunately, SRVANY sucks. There is an alternative which is the ["Non-Sucking Service Manager" (NSSM)](http://iain.cx/src/nssm/) - it will shut down your application and all child processes on the service stop signal.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, srvany.exe does not provide any method for killing the process(es) when the service is stopped, so basically your options are to (a) look for a third-party alternative which does provide this functionality or (b) write such a replacement yourself.

Perhaps another reader knows about a good third-party alternative, or you might get lucky with a Google search.  If you decide to go with option (b) I may be able to give you a head start, so drop me an email if you like - my address is in my profile.  Or you could post a question to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Srvany has a few well known shortcomings, one of which is [not terminating the process it starts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424374/windows-srvany-exe-and-service-stop).

Be sure to read about other potential issues on [this page comparing Srvany to AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/srvany.html) (our commercial application which will close all sub-processes as you expect) to reduce the surprises...